# Python request API

Tags: python, api, dataframe, loops, request

I'm trying to retrieve some data off the NOAA API, but there is an error that I'm not able to resolve

```
    location=[]
def find_xy(Name, lat, long):
    api = url+str(lat)+','+str(long)
    r = requests.get(api).json()
    x = r['properties']['gridX']
    y = r['properties']['gridY']
    xy=(Name, str(lat), str(long), x, y)
    location.append(xy)

for i in dfgrid:
    Name = dfgrid['Name']
    lat =  dfgrid['Lat']
    long =  dfgrid['Long']    
    find_xy(Name,lat,long)
```

There is a list of lat and longs in dfgrid, I'd like to loop through each coordinate and grab the gridX and gridY values in the NOAA API

I'm able to pull this data using one example but when I try to loop through the entire dfgrid I receive the following error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 3     lat =  dfgrid['Lat']
> 4     long =  dfgrid['Long']
> ----> 5     find_xy(Name,lat,long)
>
> in find_xy(Name, lat, long)
> 3     api = url+str(lat)+','+str(long)
> 4     r = requests.get(api).json()
> ----> 5     x = r['properties']['gridX']
> 6     y = r['properties']['gridY']
> 7     xy=(Name, str(lat), str(long), x, y)
>
> KeyError: 'properties'

Comment: Have you tried doing some simple debugging like printing `r` before trying to access `r[‘properties’]`? Or try being defensive: use `r.get(‘properties’)` and check the result is not `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by

```
dfgrid = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Name','Lat','Long'])

dfgrid['Lat']=dfgrid['Lat'].astype(str)

dfgrid['Long']=dfgrid['Long'].astype(str)

dfgrid['coordinate']= dfgrid['Lat']+","+dfgrid['Long']
```

What I was doing before was adding the Lat and Long even though I str() both the Lat and Long float... This gave the error on the API request. Still trying to process why str(Lat)+","+str(Long) didn't work, but regardless I found a solution.

Thanks everyone who tried to help. Very much appreciated.
Mike